# Unable to retrieve data because name or service not known while querying del.icio.us API with get_popular

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling to get dataset of tags and items from del.icio.us API. I have been provided some functions

- to find all users who posted something related to a tag
- find items/links posted by all those users.

So from this I am able to create a dataset of items/urls and users according to a tag but I haven't succeeded yet to create a dataset of tags and items/urls. Indeed when using `get_popular(tag = 'your-tag')` it always give me the following pydelicious exception :

```
pydelicious.PyDeliciousException: Unable to retrieve data at 'http://feeds.delicious.com/rss/popular/programming', <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Here is my attempt if you want to try and reproduce the error :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pydelicious import get_popular, get_userposts, get_urlposts
import time


def initializeUserDict(tag, count=5):
    user_dict = {}
    # get the top count' popular posts
    for p1 in get_popular(tag=tag)[0:count]:
        print 'yeah'
    # find all users who posted this
        for p2 in get_urlposts(p1['href']):
            user = p2['user']
            user_dict[user] = {}
    return user_dict


def fillItems(user_dict):
    all_items = {}
    # Find links posted by all users
    for user in user_dict:
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                posts = get_userposts(user)
                break
            except:
                print 'Failed user ' + user + ', retrying'
                time.sleep(4)
        for post in posts:
            url = post['href']
            user_dict[user][url] = 1.0
            all_items[url] = 1

    # Fill in missing items with 0
    for ratings in user_dict.values():
        for item in all_items:
            if item not in ratings:
                ratings[item] = 0.0


def initializeTagDict(user_dict, count=5):
    tag_dict = {}
    # get the user and items

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #print "starting hotlist retrieval"
    delusers = initializeUserDict('programming')
    fillItems(delusers)
    # I have a dataset of user and items, according to a tag how to create a dataset of tags and items ?
    # I want to provide nothing and only get the most popular tags and items
    import deliciousapi
    dapi = deliciousapi.DeliciousAPI()
    url = "http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Del.icio.us_Python_API"

    # web pages shown on the front page of Delicious.com aka the 'hotlist'
    featured_links = dapi.get_urls()

    print "starting retrieval"
    import pycurl
    import StringIO

    response = StringIO.StringIO()
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, featured_links[0])
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
    c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','Accept-Charset: UTF-8'])
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, '@request.json')
    c.perform()
    c.close()
    print response.getvalue()
    response.close()

    # Here I would have had the tags, I now need the items
```

This is from exercise 2 of [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://github.com/ShawnLeee/the-book/blob/master/pybooks/Programming%20Collective%20Intelligence.pdf) by T. Segaran.

> *Tag similarity*. Using the del.icio.us API create a dataset of tags and items. Use this to calculate similarity between tags and see if you can find any that are almost identical. Find some items that could have been tagged programming but were not.

I used python2.7, as they do in the book, but use any version you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the endpoint http://feeds.delicious.com you're trying to hit does not resolve.  I have tried adding endpoint and its various combinations to my local rss feed reader but it was unable to resolve any of them either.

If the API is down, you could try notifying whoever is responsible for its maintenance.